# Y offset position and active class state

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the Y offset positions of the sections in viewport and adding an active state to the equivalent menu item, but it does not work, any help please?

```
// Get the Y offset position of the sections in viewport
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll("allSections");

allSections.forEach( (section) => {
     allSections.scrollingElement.scrollTop = section.offsetTop;
     section.innerText = "Y offset after scrolling: " +
                 allSections.contentWindow.pageYOffset + " pixels";

     allSections.classList.add('active');

} )
```

HTML

```
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class section">
      <div class="landing__container active">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.navbar__menu li:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ff6666;
}

.navbar__menu li:active active {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: `allSections.classList.add` should be `section.classList.add`, you can't add a class to a `NodeList`

Comment: Also, `"allSections"` isn't a valid selector, you'd have to do something like `document.querySelectorAll("section")`